# Clair scanner shows Unknown Severity for Debian based docker images

Tags: docker, security, docker-registry, clair

I have OpenShift with Clair set up. Clair scanner scans for vulnerabilities in docker images.

Is it possible to get High and Critical severity levels while using Clair scanner v4 to scan Debian based docker images?

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/arminc/clair-scanner there is a parameter `--threshold` "CVE severity threshold. Valid values; 'Defcon1', 'Critical', 'High', 'Medium', 'Low', 'Negligible', 'Unknown'" is this what you mean?

Comment: @DanielW. you're referring to old Clair - this is new one.

Comment: I have exact same problem with mine vulnerability report... In Clair v2 there was `severity` in the output json field, with values shared by @DanielW. . In V4 it returns `severity` field as well, but it's empty for me also...

Comment: You should open an issue here: https://github.com/quay/clair/issues

Comment: @DanielW. I found this on their web page https://quay.github.io/claircore/concepts/severity_mapping.html
*Debian Mapping - Debian Oval database does not provide severity information. All vulnerability severities will be Unknown.*

Hence, my original question. So far my choice is to use Trivy to scan Debian based images to get High and Critical issues.